# Pass param to @proxy location?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I'd like to set up nuxt with NGINX as load balancer. Additionally, I'd like to add some caching to the images.

Now I get 404 for my images using this:

```
    location ~ ^/img.+\.(?:ico|gif|jpe?g|webp|png|woff2?|eot|otf|ttf|svg|js|css)$ {
        expires 365d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";

        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }
    
    location @proxy {
        expires 365d;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_ignore_headers        Cache-Control;
        proxy_http_version          1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass http://1649681_app/$request_uri;
        #proxy_cache                 nuxt-cache;
        #proxy_cache_bypass          $arg_nocache; # probably better to change this
        #proxy_cache_valid           200 302  60m; # set this to your needs
        #proxy_cache_valid           404      1m;  # set this to your needs
        #proxy_cache_lock            on;
        #proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        #proxy_cache_key             $uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

It seems like `$request_uri` is wrong in the line `proxy_pass http://1649681_app/$request_uri` - but how can I pass the requested path to the `@proxy`-location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't completely wrong to specify an URI using variables for the `proxy_pass` directive inside the named (as well as the regex) locations. However such a thing will have a drawback - if you can't specify your upstream address using IP rather than hostname, you'll need either a [`resolver`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) defined in your configuration (worse) or an additional `upstream` block to define your `1649681_app` backend (better). More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72263129/7121513) (exactly the same is applicable to named locations too).

Being that said, how do you think, what a request URI will be passed to the upstream specified in the `proxy_pass` directive if you won't specify any explicitly? It will be **exactly** the URI being processed (and if for some reason you'd need to pass a modified URI instead, you'd need to to modify it via the `rewrite` rules).

For the given configuration, assuming you don't need to modify the request URI or query arguments, you should simply use the

```
proxy_pass http://1649681_app;
```

And, do you understand what the `$uri/` parameter does exactly mean? It makes the `try_files` directive to check if the given URI is a directory to search an index file inside it. I really doubt you need it using **that** kind of regex pattern. Remove it, it is only an extra (some kind of expensive) system kernel `stat` call. Use

```
try_files $uri @proxy;
```

instead.

Comment: Adding `proxy_pass http://1649309_app/;` leads to error " "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block"

Comment: Is it the line I suggest to use in my answer? Didn't you see a difference between `proxy_pass http://1649309_app/;` and `proxy_pass http://1649309_app;`? Those two are completely different things!

Comment: Such a bone-headed mistake. I did not check, that the trailing slash actually "means" something. Thanks.

Comment: It does mean a lot. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx) thread for an example.