# Route different base path to same proxy pass Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to pass different path to the same proxy_pass but I keep getting 502 Bad gateway.

These path use the same port number but different base path. How do I make it work from what I have which returns an error currently.

this is what my current location looks like

```
worker_processes 4;
# worker_process auto
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    server {

        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/api/v1/(wallet|card)/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/$1/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting captured regex group using nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260921/redirecting-captured-regex-group-using-nginx)

Comment: I don’t think so because the answer there means any path can be passed prior. I only want my own defined path like wallet or card

Comment: I think you didn't read the answer carefully (or did I wrote it so badly?) Use `location ~ /api/v1/(?<service>wallet|card)/ { rewrite ^ /api/v1/$service/ break; proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007; ... }`

Comment: So this works but something weird. every url now has to end with `/` and some endpoints that require no authorization are now returning 401 error. @IvanShatsky

Comment: I used rewrite rule similar to what you are using in your original question. If you need to pass the URI including the suffix after `(wallet|card)`, you don't need to rewrite anything at all, use `location ~ /api/v1/(wallet|card)/ { proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007; ... }`

Comment: Can you add it as an answer so I select it. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need an URI to be changed at all, don't use anything other than the upstream name:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/(wallet|card)/ {
    proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007;
    ...
}
```

If an URI needs to be rewritten before being passed to the upstream, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72263129/7121513) answer to see how to do it.